# How to remove or insert substrings from an r variable without using system() and sed?

Tags: regex, r

I want to be able to remove or insert arbitrary substrings from an existing r variable. My current solution uses `system()`, but I'm sure there's an easier and more elegant way:

```
> filename <- "remove_this_my_file.txt"
> (file <- system(paste("echo ", filename, "| sed 's/remove_this_\\(.*\\)/\\1/'",sep=""), intern=T))
[1] "my_file.txt"
```

By the way, `substr()` is no good, since the position of the substring might vary from filename to filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in R via the `grep`, `sub`, `regexpr`, and similar commands.  It sounds like you'd want `sub` or `gsub`.  These operations are vectorized, which comes in handy at times.

```
> filename <- sub("remove_this_","",filename)
> filename
[1] "my_file.txt"
```

If you're used to Perl-style regular expressions, you'll want to set the `,perl=TRUE` option.